# Необходимо найти вероятность появления единицы в первой позиции кодового слова

Tags: информатика, теория-вероятностей

Сообщения { X1,X2,X3,X4} источника, заданного распределением вероятностей {p1,p2,p3,p4}, кодируются словами: {00},{01},{10},{11} соответственно. Необходимо найти вероятность появления единицы в первой позиции кодового слова при условии, что во второй позиции кодового слова появилась единица; вероятность появления нуля во второй позиции кодового слова при условии, что в первой позиции кодового слова появился нуль; вероятность появления сообщения x2 при условии, что в первой позиции кодового слова появился нуль. Исходные данные:

P1 = 0,2 + 0.005 * N

P2 = 0,3 - 0.005 * N

P3 = 0,1 + 0.01 * N

P4 = 0,4 - 0.01 * N

N=4

Подскажите с чего начать? Спасибо.

Comment: Вам поможет изучение условной вероятности и теоремы Байеса

Comment: У вас неверно заданы исходные данные - сумма вероятностей `p1 + p2 + p3 + p4` не равна 1.

Comment: @Yaant да, была ошибка. Поправил условия.

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев А можете подробнее ход решения описать?

Comment: Причем тут вообще криптография?

Comment: У нас вообще-то не сервис по решению учебных задач. Ну и к программированию ваша задача отношения не имеет.

Comment: @VladD сервис по нравоучениям это. Англоязычный сервис другое дело.

Comment: @Zverit: А вы попробуйте! Увидите, с какой скоростью подобный вопрос будет заминусован и закрыт.